# NativeScript ListView dosnt work. i dont see the data

Tags: listview, nativescript, ng-template

i have `task-component.ts` that contain some data in `userTaskList` array.
now i want to display this data to the user.

i want to use `<ListView>` to display the data.

here is what i did :

task-component.ts :

```
 public userTaskList: any;
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.userTaskList = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskService.getAllTasks().toPromise().then(res => {
      this.userTaskList=res;
      this.zone.run(()=>{})
      console.log("data is here ! ==>>> ", this.userTaskList);
    })

  }
```

task-component.html:

```
<ActionBar title="Task List">
  <NavigationButton text="Go Back" icon="res://back" ></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>
<ListView [userTaskList]="myTasks" >
    <ng-template let-task="task" >
  <StackLayout >
      <Label [text]= task.Name ></Label>
      <Button text="Add" class="submit-button" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
      <Button text="logOut" class="submit-button" (tap)="logOut()"></Button>
      <Button text="ShowToken" class="submit-button" (tap)="Tokenv()"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</ng-template>
</ListView>
```

i don't get any Extantions and even the buttons are disappeard when i run it.
all i see is blank page.

can you tell me what am i doing wrong?
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<ListView [userTaskList]="myTasks" >
```

To

```
<ListView [items]="userTaskList"  >
```

And change :

```
<ng-template let-task="task" >
```

To

```
 <ng-template let-task="item" >
```

Also   , you forgot `"` in :

```
 <Label [text]= task.Name ></Label>
```

So it should be :

```
<Label [text]= "task.Name" ></Label>
```

Listview requires `[items]`  to be the property name.

BTW  -you don't need ngZone here. (And a friendly advice , work with observables. not promises).